# I get a fail when I run make, cannot resolve why

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, java

Here is my problem and it occurs on every version of RXTX I try to compile.
I am using Ubuntu 18.04
GCC is 7.4

The last lines of my compilation:

```
/bin/bash: /usr/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac: No such file or directory
```

I'm not true if it exists and my path exists as does JAVA_HOME etc.

This is the problem:

```
Makefile:610: recipe for target '/home/david/hidden/rxtx-devel/gnu/io/RawPortEventListener.class' failed
make: *** [/home/david/hidden/rxtx-devel/gnu/io/RawPortEventListener.class] Error 127
make: Target 'all' not remade because of errors.
```

I have no idea what this is trying to do because it is derived from this code on line 610 of the Makefile:
(JAVA_FIX)

Any help/ideas about the problem resolution?

David

Makefile entry:

## compile src/RXTXPort.java and similar files into classes

## then create the .jar file

$(CLASSES): $(javafiles) $(TOP)/Makefile 
  $(JAVAH_FIX)
  $(JAVAC) $(javafiles)
  $(JAVAH) (for i in $(javahfiles);do \
          if grep > /dev/null native.*( $(SPATH)/gnu/io/$$i.java; then \
               echo $(CLASSDIR).$$i; \ 
         fi; \
  done)`
  $(JAR) cf $(JARTARGET) $(CLASSTOP)/*

I understand that Error 127 is a bash error not a makefile error.

Comment: Makefile entry:

#  compile src/RXTXPort.java and similar files into classes
#  then create the .jar file
$(CLASSES): $(javafiles) $(TOP)/Makefile
 $(JAVAH_FIX)
 $(JAVAC) $(javafiles)
 $(JAVAH) `(for i in $(javahfiles);do \
  if grep > /dev/null native.*\( $(SPATH)/gnu/io/$$i.java; then \
   echo $(CLASSDIR).$$i; \
  fi; \
 done)`
 $(JAR) cf $(JARTARGET) $(CLASSTOP)/*

I understand that Error 127 is a bash error not a makefile error.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button to put this comment into the question. also, fix formatting while you're at it :)

Answer (score 1):

In first instance, try with these command for understand if the javac is really installed:

```bsh
java -version
which java
```

If you can see the path related to java, than you have to set your JAVA_PATH as the line returned by `which java` without the `/bin` final folder

So, assume that you have java located at `/opt/SP/SDK/Java1.8/bin/java`, you have to type the following commands:

```bsh
echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/opt/SP/SDK/Java1.8' >>/home/$(whoami)/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin' >>/home/$(whoami)/.bashrc
source $_
```

In case that java is not found, you have to install java

- Downloading a compliant jdk and setting the path
- `apt-get install default-jdk`

Comment: I tried but it appears that java is not installed even though running these tells me it is.
Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install default-jre            
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless

Comment: After set JAVA_HOME and PATH+JAVA_HOME have you ran `source /home/$(whoami)/.bashrc`?

Comment: I uninstalled all java items and will start from scratch because the files were in unexpected places. Maybe a bad install

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled a an improperly working Java, and I am now in the process of re-installing this program. It wasn't a question of a fault in others programming but was a question of me not clearly understanding my Java installation and Java itself. I am on a new path to rectify that by reinstalling from scratch Java and subsequently coming to understand java better. Thanks for all the help.